# How much does one have to eat to become Fleishigs?

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Is there a minimum amount of meat or chicken required to be eaten in order to change one's status to being "fleishig" (i.e. so that he would have to wait before eating dairy)?

[same question can be said of dairy for "milchig" status...]

Would it matter if the meat or chicken is spit from the mouth before swallowing?

Comment: of course CYLOR

Comment: I don't have a source, but I believe there is a halachic status of 'tasting', and if you 'taste' you are not fleishic. This would basically mean, less than a kzayit.

Comment: to avi - that is an incorrect assumption - any small amount of actual eating would make one fleishig - the shulchan aruch rules even chewing and spitting out would enough to mandate waiting 6 hours. for fuller details see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The [Taz](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=397) (Yoreh Deah 89:1) says that there are two reasons for waiting after meat. One (Rashi's) reason is that meat gives flavor and the flavor stays in the throat for six hours. The other (Rambam's) reason is because meat which stays in between the teeth is called meat, and eating milk afterwords would result in eating milk and meat.

Therefore, according to Rashi, after chewing meat one would not have to wait six hours, but according to the Rambam one would. The Taz says to be stringent like both opinions.

With regards to milk, technically you don't have to wait at all. However, the [Zohar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14242&st=&pgnum=413) requires one to wait an hour.

Comment: The flavor reason applies AFAIK only if it's swallowed, which your wording ("meat gives flavor and the flavor stays in the mouth") could make clearer.... Also, +1 for addressing the second question ("Would it matter if the meat or chicken is spit"), but this doesn't seem to address the first at all. Finally, what about spitting out something that doesn't get stuck in the teeth (e.g. chicken (or even meat) soup, without any of the chicken/meat)? (I learned about this case, but would have to check my notes before writing _what_ I learned about it.)

Comment: @msh210, My rav said regarding someone who was carrying a tray of cholent and licked off his finger some of the "cholent juice", that he is not *fleishig* at all, since neither rashi's nor the rambam's opinion applies (it was not enough to swallow).

Comment: @jake - sounds like an answer to me. Not a particularly universal source, but it's more than we've got so far.

Comment: see here for a thorough analysis for waiting after dairy -http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5175

Comment: lo plug -pri megadfim

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is not entirely correct, as although the shulchan aruch does not hold of a tavshil shel basar - both by bb"c and nine days, - as opposed to the rema - many later sefardic authorities including ben ish chai, chida, zivchei tzedek and kaf hachaim are makpid for it. Therefore as soon as one swallows even that he would need to wait 6 hours- as we are machmir for both rashi and rambams opinions. - shu"a yd 89, 1
see related article [here:](http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/4851) - in the postscript.

Regarding placing in mouth and spitting out - it is the shitta of the maharshak that one only requires a rinse - I havent come across any one arguing.

Regarding chewing and spitting out - although shulchan aruch and others inc. pmg are stringent to wait full 6 hors, r akina eiger, yad yehuda and aruch hashulchan are medayek from rema that 1 hour is enough.
see related great article [here](http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5058):- end of article.

I learned so much from this Rabbi Spitz's Halacha column and I find that many of these questions here are answered by his wise words.

Comment: why the downvote? this answer is not only thorough but even clear! i gave it a thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

One of the differences between Ashkenazim and Sephardim is that Ashkenazim become basari after eating even tavshil shel basar, whereas Sephardim only have to rinse their mouths out and wait a short amount of time.

Comment: Adam and @Vram Your answers would be greatly improved by citing sources.

Comment: Thanks for the mareh makom, Vram.  In addition to the gemara there, notice how Tosfos quote Rabbeinu Shmuel (aka Rashbam) and Rabbeinu Tam.

Comment: The source here is Maran in Yore Deah. However, it should be noted that Hacham Ovadia rules like that one should strict like the Rama here because that is the Minhag.