# Does consuming raw meat make one Fleishigs?

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher, meat, meat-and-milk

If one is making meat, and while the meat is still raw licks his/her fingers, does s/he become Fleishigs (to wait the appropriate amount of time before eating dairy)?

Essentially if we boil (excuse the pun) the question down a bit more, does inedible meat or chicken make one Fleishigs?

(for purposes of this question, I suppose we should disregard [the potential volume aspects](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10165/how-much-does-one-have-to-eat-to-become-fleishigs))

Comment: Consult a medical practitioner or dietician about the advisability of licking fingers dirty from raw chicken anyway. And, as always, CYLOR about the halachic question, rather than relying on answers here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Who said that raw meat is inedible? The Shulchan Aruch rules in Hilchot Shabbat that raw meat is not Muktzeh on Shabbat since there are people who eat it as a delicacy (ie Steak Tartar).

Comment: Would you say that about chicken?

Comment: See the mishna menachot 11:7

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for waiting some time after eating meat is because, a) the juices stay in ones mouth on the tongue etc., and b) strands of meat get stuck in between teeth. As such, one would have to wait after eating raw meat too.

Comment: Maybe raw meat doesn't have the kind of juices that get stuck?

Answer (score -1):

there are two opinions about why one waits after eating meat that impact Halacha. one is the Rambam who says that after eating meat the meat gets stuck in your teeth and his reasoning is quoting the genera in chillin 105a. The other opinion is Rashi. Rashi gives the reason that the tastes of the meat stays in ones mouth and he quotes the Chumash (in parishes b'halosecha ch 11 הַבָּשָׂ֗ר עוֹדֶ֨נּוּ֙ בֵּ֣ין שִׁנֵּיהֶ֔ם טֶ֖רֶם יִכָּרֵ֑ת וְאַ֤ף יְהֹוָה֙ חָרָ֣ה בָעָ֔ם וַיַּ֤ךְ יְהֹוָה֙ בָּעָ֔ם מַכָּ֖ה רַבָּ֥ה מְאֹֽד:) for his reason. This means that if one only chewed meat but did not swallow one would have to wait b/c the meat gets stuck in your teeth and if one ate meat but did not chew one would still have to wait b/c the taste of the meat will still be in your mouth. There is no explicit mention of a difference between raw meat and cooked meat nor do I think there is a logical reason to make a difference between the two in regards to how long ones waits after eating meat.