# Can Food Remnants make you fleishig/milchig

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher, clothing, meat-and-milk

ב"ה
Can food remnants, like stains, make you fleishig/milchig?

For example, if I had a steak and got it on my sleeve, then the next day wiped my mouth with that sleev,e can I become fleishig from that? Another recurring instance is that I'll be eating and I'll have some grease on my hand, and I'll say Birkat Hamazon on my phone. Then later, I'll touch/use my phone, and then unintentionally touch my mouth or what not. Is the grease/remnants that are on the phone liable to make me fleishig/milchig?

Include sources if possible.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch 89 discusses this with bread by a meat seudua should not be eaten with dairy,but eating that bread wont make you fleishig ,see star k website

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10165

Comment: Better question: can you wash a shirt with milk stains and a shirt with meat stains in the same washing machine?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I actually once asked R' Dovid Fink in Jerusalem a similar question. My exact question was about pouring hot water on trash that contained milk and meat, since it would seem to cook them. He brought down a halakha that back when incinerators were common in apartment buildings, people became concerned that they would have to have separate milchig and fleishig trash cans so they wouldn't "cook" them together. But, in fact, it is permissible to throw out everything in a single bag, because the process of incineration isn't "cooking." (Also, the hot water is permissible as well)

Comment: Lately I keep thinking about all the times in the past I'd be sure to stop eating meat at Shabbath lunch by a certain time to ensure I'd be able to eat dairy at a certain later time. But I'd eat salad or side dishes. On the same plate. With meat remnants/grease.